# Update multiple tables in trigger where one of the tables is used for trigger activation

Tags: sql, mariadb

Let's say I have two tables called `widgetCustomer` and `widgetSale`. On an insert in `widgetSale` I want to add a timestamp to the `widgetSale` row and add the sale `id` as `last_order_id` to the  `widgetCustomer` table.

I understand using `AFTER INSERT ON` will result in an error on trying to update the `NEW` row, hence we need to use `BEFORE INSERT ON` clause. Which brings forward a new issue that `AUTO_INCREMENT` has not yet generated a id for sale hence last_order_id would all be zero. There is a method to do this at [MySQL/MariaDB TRIGGER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31176136/mysql-mariadb-trigger) but it seems to fail on my system (i.e., the last order ids are still zero).

As a work around I'm using two different triggers one before insert and one after insert. Although it does work I'm keen to learn if there is a possible flaws with the method above and is there a better way of doing this (both in terms of performance and data integrity).

My code is given below:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS widgetSale;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS widgetCustomer;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS widgetLog;

CREATE TABLE widgetCustomer ( id integer primary key AUTO_INCREMENT, name TEXT, last_order_id INT, stamp TEXT );
CREATE TABLE widgetSale ( id integer primary key AUTO_INCREMENT, item_id INT, customer_id INTEGER, quan INT, price INT, stamp TEXT );
CREATE TABLE widgetLog ( id integer primary key AUTO_INCREMENT, stamp TEXT, event TEXT, username TEXT, tablename TEXT, table_id INT);

INSERT INTO widgetCustomer (name) VALUES ('Bob');
INSERT INTO widgetCustomer (name) VALUES ('Sally');
INSERT INTO widgetCustomer (name) VALUES ('Fred');
SELECT * FROM widgetCustomer;

CREATE TRIGGER stampSale BEFORE INSERT ON widgetSale
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        SET NEW.stamp = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP();
    END
    
CREATE TRIGGER stampOnRest AFTER INSERT ON widgetSale
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
        UPDATE widgetCustomer SET last_order_id = NEW.id, stamp = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
            WHERE widgetCustomer.id = NEW.customer_id;
        INSERT INTO widgetLog (stamp, event, username, tablename, table_id)
            VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), 'INSERT', 'TRIGGER', 'widgetSale', NEW.id);
    END



INSERT INTO widgetSale (item_id, customer_id, quan, price) VALUES (1, 3, 5, 1995);
INSERT INTO widgetSale (item_id, customer_id, quan, price) VALUES (2, 2, 3, 1495);
INSERT INTO widgetSale (item_id, customer_id, quan, price) VALUES (3, 1, 1, 2995);

SELECT * FROM widgetSale;
SELECT * FROM widgetCustomer;
SELECT * FROM widgetLog;
```

I'm using mariadb 10.6.* on Archlinux.

Comment: Curious why `stamp` in all three tables does not default to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` at the table level as date/time (or timestamp) instead of text? ... one less trigger need, a few less columns to handle.

Comment: @PaulT. it is just to demonstrate this specific case ....  sadly this was the quickest example that popped up in my head :D

Comment: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=6acf082bacd5fafb62055c93f44fa956) shows the right results of the trigger for me. Or did I misread something?

Comment: @danblack a better way to look at this would be "is there a way to reconcile the above scenario within a single trigger without bringing forth new issues".

Comment: a before trigger is different from an after trigger because of all the reasons you've said. There's no reconciliation needed or possible. MariaDB even support multiple triggers for the same table/trigger_time/trigger_event from 10.2. Multiple triggers aren't necessary a bad thing.